# Combine duplicate column values EXCEL

Tags: excel

Good afternoon.

I have an Excel Question

How to get from this to this.

```
A       DFG 

A       ASD

C       DD              

A       144                     

C       XX                      

B       $%                      

------------
A   DFG ASD 144

B   $%

C   XX  DD
```

I tried with Index but I am not able to get the desired results.

Any idea>

Thanks

Comment: Absolutely,
 My solution was send it to SQL and use STUFF  FOR XML PATH.
But in Excel im stuck

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I used this formula after sorting by column A and column B
=IF(A2=A1,C1&", "&B2,B2)

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in columns A and B, then try:

```
F7:  =IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/1/($A:$A=$E7)*ROW($A:$A),COLUMNS($A:A))),"")
```

Fill down and to the right as needed (until you see blanks)

where `G7` contains the item in column A you are looking for

[image]